# Resizing a BitmapSource

Tags: c#, bitmap, emgucv, bitmapsource

I have a Image in xaml that I'm trying to set the source of but I noticed the scale of the image when I read it in is getting changed which I do not want to happen. The goal is to get Image.Source to have the same width and height as the original image read in.

This is the Code I have so far

```
// Get a specific page then display it.
Emgu.CV.Mat[]? emguPageMats = CvInvoke.Imreadmulti(randomTestPreviewPath, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Color);
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte> emguImage = emguPageMats[0].ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
Debug.Print(emguPageMats[0].Width + ", " + emguPageMats[0].Height); -> **returns 1700, 2200**
image.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapSource(emguImage.ToBitmap(), emguImage);
Debug.Print(image.Source.Width + ", " + image.Source.Height); -> **returns 1360, 1760**
```

Here is the conversion method im using which I found here on Stack Overflow that I renamed **ConvertBitmapToBitmapSource()**

```
public static BitmapSource ConvertBitmapToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap, 
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte> emguImage)
{
    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, emguImage.Width, emguImage.Height),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(
    bitmapData.Width, bitmapData.Height,
    bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution,
    PixelFormats.Bgr24, null,
    bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return bitmapSource;
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

**Edit 1:** I found that the actual size of a BitmapSource is in BitmapSource.PixelWidth & BitmapSource.PixelHeight. Not sure how to get image.Source to become that size though...

**Edit 2:** Alright I think I got it. Could it be nicer? Probably.

```
// Get a specific page then display it.
Emgu.CV.Mat[]? emguPageMats = CvInvoke.Imreadmulti(randomTestPreviewPath,                     
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Color);
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte> emguImage = emguPageMats[0].ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
maxPages = emguPageMats.Count();
image.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapSource(emguImage.ToBitmap(), emguImage);
// Calculate Scaling using dpi.Y and dpi.Y are 120, guess it doesn't matter what I use
double d = (1d / 96) * dpi.X;
var finalWidth = image.Source.Width * d;
var finalHeight = image.Source.Height * d;
Debug.Print("final: " + finalWidth + ", " + finalHeight);
// Sets the width and height based on the dpi which is essentially pixelWidth & pixelHeight
image.Width = finalWidth;
image.Height = finalHeight;
Debug.Print("image: " + finalWidth + ", " + finalHeight);
```

This is for the dpi if anyone wants it.

```
public static System.Drawing.PointF dpi;
// For grabbing screen dpi to help with resizing the window
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    dpi.X = graphics.DpiX;
    dpi.Y = graphics.DpiY;
}
```

Comment: When dealing with bitmapSource, remember to use PixelWidth/PixelHeight if you want the size in pixels, not the width/height.

Comment: @JonasH Yeah I just saw that. Is the easiest way to go about this to do math on the return width and height with the 1/96th thing referenced to get the true dimensions?

Comment: If the goal is to display the image in a 1:1 scale on the screen you should probably look at the scale of the actual wpf image, not the bitmapSource. But note that 1:1 scale may depend on window scaling etc. Talking about "size" for an image tend to get complicated if you are not just counting pixels.

Comment: @JonasH Yes. The goal is to display 1:1 in the XAML Image (which is in a scroll viewer). I have a way to get the users dpi currently. Just confused on how to apply it.